# How to connect to MongoDB server and npm start at the same time for MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am making a MERN app and I notice that every time I want it to work, I have to first connect to the MongoDB server by "node server.js".
Then, I have to do "npm start" to run the react app which is connected to the server I just connected to.

Is there a way to do both of these actions using one command?

Comment: by doing `node server.js` you are running the backend, which internally connects to Mongo DB.
Here is what you can do to: `node <path to your server.js> && npm start` 
this will run first the backend then will start your react app.

Comment: during the development, I suggest running them separately and `watch` for changes so that you don't have to run these commands whenever you change the code. you can achieve that for your server app with [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/). you can still run commands simultaneously but debugging might get harder at times. in production I suggest using [pm2](https://pm2.io/).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I can establish the connection with the server. It shows that I have connected to the server successfully but it does not let me write any more commands unless I open a new terminal window or press Ctrl C. I want the script to open the connection with the server and then do npm start. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this for production, then you could use nodemon, which is a good tool that hot reloads your server and front end.

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "SET THIS=development & nodemon server.js",
```

},

Also, make sure you're server JS has a catch all that points to your app, such as:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
})




 backend
 - - server.js //with mongodb connection, and api routes.  
//This is what you are going to use for your API calls from the front end. i.e http://backend.com/userapi/


 frontend
 - - server.js that contains the catch all statment.  Also would add custom routes in here i.e

server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
    return app.render(req, res, '/article', { id: req.params.id })
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I can establish the connection with the server. It shows that I have connected to the server successfully but it does not let me write any more commands unless I open a new terminal window or press Ctrl C. I want the script to open the connection with the server and then do npm start. How would I do that?

Comment: you could add npm start afterwards, but you shouldn't need to, si the server.js file in the root of your project?

Comment: If you have a server in the backend, and that's what you're using, you need to create a server.js file in the front end as well, that's used for routing.  The mongodb connection needs to be in the backend server.js file

Comment: my server.js file is not in the root, it is in another directory which is at the root. Does it need to be in the root?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer and it didn't save.  Check out again

Comment: Please see answer.  You should have one server.js in the root of your backend and one in the root of your frontend root.  I have described what to do for both.